# Why there is no gutter between the textbox and the button?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I am using bootstrap in my project. The project uses jade as view engine. I have the following code.

```
extends layout

block content
    .container
        .row
            .col-md-4.col-md-offset-4
                .panel.panel-default
                    .panel-heading
                        h1.center-text Weather Application
                    .panel-body
                        form.form-inline
                            .form-group
                                label.sr-only(for="cityname") City name
                                input.form-control(type="text" placeholder="Enter City Name")
                            button.btn.btn-primary(type="submit") Add City
```

I dont know for some reason I am getting the html view as follows. [image]

There is no gutter between the text box and the button. Can anyone tell me the reason for this.

Answer (score 0):

For me, the above Jade compiles to:

```
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-4 col-md-offset-4">
      <div class="panel panel-default">
        <div class="panel-heading">
          <h1 class="center-text">Weather Application</h1>
        </div>
        <div class="panel-body">
          <form class="form-inline">
            <div class="form-group">
              <label for="cityname" class="sr-only">City name</label>
              <input type="text" placeholder="Enter City Name" class="form-control"/>
            </div>
            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Add City</button>
          </form>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Which ends up looking like this:

[image]

Do you have any custom CSS?

Comment: Also, unrelated, Bootstrap has the built in contextual class ".text-center", so you don't have to create a custom class to center text.

Comment: yes I have a custom css file but that only uses text-align to center.

Comment: Are you loading in any libraries other than Bootstrap? What version of Bootstrap are you using?

Comment: i m using bootstrap 3.3.6

Answer (score 0):

The code runs fine for me using bootstrap 3.3.6. There is a gutter. What version are you using?

Please check using the dev tools in your browser to see if another css class is overriding bootstrap's css.